# Integration Testing - How to hit endpoints using Microsoft.Owin.Testing.TestServer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, integration-testing, owin

I have setup a basic Web API project to test writing integration tests, with the below setup

Startup:

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WebApiTest.Startup))]

namespace WebApiTest
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            WebApiConfig.Register(new System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration());
        }
    }
}
```

And the following controller:

```
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebApiTest.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        public IHttpActionResult Post()
        {
            return Ok("Hello, world!");
        }
    }
}
```

For my Tests project I am using `NUnit` for my testing, and have two classes: an abstract `BaseTest` class, and a `ControllerTests` class which contains one test with the intention of sending a web request out to the above `TestController`'s `GET` Action method:

BaseTest:

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Testing;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace WebApiTest.Tests
{
    public abstract class BaseTest : IDisposable
    {
        protected const string _url = "http://localhost/";
        protected TestServer _server;

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _server.Dispose();
        }

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            _server = TestServer.Create<Startup>();
        }

        protected HttpRequestMessage CreateRequest(string url, string 
contentType, HttpMethod method)
        {
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                RequestUri = new Uri(_url + url),
                Method = method
            };
            request.Headers.Accept.Add(new 
System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(contentType));
            return request;
        }
    }
}
```

ControllerTests:

```
using FluentAssertions;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApiTest.Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class ControllerTests : BaseTest
    {
        [Test]
        public async Task Test1()
        {
            HttpRequestMessage request = CreateRequest("test", "application/json", HttpMethod.Post);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await _server.HttpClient.SendAsync(request);
            response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am running into is that I'm not able to reach my endpoint with the call `await _server.HttpClient.SendAsync(request);` as I always get a `404: Not Found` response.

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong, whether it be something that's not being setup property or Api routes that aren't being mapped.

**update**: Here is my `WebApiConfig.Register()` method for reference:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: I thought the `WebApiConfig.Register()` call in my `Startup` class took care of that.

Answer (score 2):

The web API was not configured correctly so the routes are not known to it

> If you are self-hosting with OWIN, create a new `HttpConfiguration` instance. Perform any configuration on this instance, and then pass the instance to the `Owin.UseWebApi` extension method.

```
public class Startup {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
        var config = new System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseWebApi(config); //<-- THIS WAS MISSING 
    }
}
```

Reference [Configuring Web API with OWIN Self-Hosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/configuring-aspnet-web-api#configuring-web-api-with-owin-self-hosting)

Comment: Is this supposed to go inside my Tests project, or my actual API project?

Comment: In your `Startup` class

Comment: After adding that line to my `Startup` class I tried posting to one of my controllers and got this error from Postman: `An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'Controller'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.`

Comment: That is usually associated with an issue when creating the controller. Are you using DI with your controller?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using `Ninject` to inject a `IUnitOfWork` and `IMapper` into my controller, for mapping DTOs and writing records to a database.

Comment: Then most likely one of the dependencies is not being injected correctly, causing the controller to fail when being created. recheck your startup and how you setup your API

Comment: I'm confused as to why `app.UseWebApi(config)` would cause some issue with DI, though.

Comment: Can you show your `WebApiConfig.Register` and how you setup the http configuration

Comment: I appended the code for the `WebApiConfig.Register` method to my question.

Comment: Not seeing where you are using DI anywhere

Comment: I have a `NinjectWebCommon` class that has a `Start` method which gets executed as soon as the application starts, and that is responsible for binding. Not sure if that would affect anything.

Comment: yes it would affect things since it is not being called in the test. The TestServer know nothing about it. it is most likely using global configuration.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that my Tests project was not aware of all the DI my API was doing at startup, since all the code for that was not contained within my `Startup`'s `Configuration` method.

In a older version of my code I had the below two lines in my `Configuration` method:

```
app.UseNinjectMiddleware(NinjectWebCommon.CreateKernel);
app.UseNinjectWebApi(configuration);
```

Back when I deleted these two lines out of the `Configuration` method I did not understand why they were there. If the dependencies are bound at startup, it would seem that these two lines are just redundant.

While that is true, in the case of referencing this `Startup` class from my Tests project, I need both of those so my Test project can handle dependencies correctly.